# Demo for wf_simulator advanced options

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello @TakaHoribe,

Nice work with the wf_simulator. I would like to know the scientific bases, if there are papers or articles that could help understand the different simulation models (based on delays introduced).

Also if there is a tutorial explaining how to tune the wf_simulator parameter.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369608/demo-for-wf_simulator-advanced-options/) by [Hatem](https://answers.ros.org/users/41954/hatem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 443 on 2021-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Hatem, Thanks for your question. Unfortunately, there is no document or academic papers for the vehicle model in wf_simulator.

I will write a detailed explanation below.

- The `IDEAL_TWIST` model drives the vehicle according to the indicated `twist` command. The vehicle position and attitude are calculated as the integrals of `twist.linear.x` and `twist.angular.z`, respectively.
- In the `IDEAL_STEER` model, the vehicle is driven according to the `control_cmd` commands (steering and velocity). `wheelbase` parameter is required to convert from steering to angular velocity using the two-wheel kinematics model.
- The `DELAY_TWIST` model uses a first-order delay model to approximate the response of the twist command to vx and wz. There are `time constant` and `time delay` parameters for the delay model.
- The `DELAY_STEER`, like DELAY_TWIST, approximates the response to control_cmd with a first-order delay model.

These delay models are the most common and simplest modeling methods and are useful for verifying the vibration and stability of closed-loop systems. You can estimate these delay parameters from the actual vehicle data. There are some pages describing the 1st order + time delay model, for example, [here](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/FirstOrderSystems).

- The `CONST_ACCEL_TWIST` is a slightly special model that basically follows the velocity indication ideally, but the velocity changes with a fixed acceleration value. Therefore, there is no sudden start or stop. This model has been in wf_simulator for a long time and is used when you want to reproduce simpler and slightly more realistic behavior than the DELAY model.

I hope this could help your work. Please let me know if there is any other information you would like to know.

---

Originally posted by [TakaHoribe](https://answers.ros.org/users/42648/takahoribe/) with karma: 181 on 2021-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hatem](https://answers.ros.org/users/41954/hatem/) on 2021-01-18**:
@TakaHoribe - san, Thank you very much.

That is very useful.